# Create a shortcode that displays an individual element "sale percentage" for WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, themes, divide-by-zero

I need to create a shortcode that display the sale percentage of a product on sale in a WooCommerce system.

I added this code in function.php of my theme to display the percentage after price and it works fine:

```
// Add save percent next to sale item prices.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    return $price . sprintf( __(' Save %s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );
}
```

now I tried to edit it to get a new shortcode but with no results:

```
// Add save percent next to sale item prices.
add_shortcode('sale_percentage', 'sale_percentage_shortcode');
function sale_percentage_shortcode( $price, $product ) {
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    return "<span>Meno $percentage %</span>";
}
```

All values are 0 and I get some warning messages like this:

> Warning: Division by zero in /web/htdocs/www.domain.com/home/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php on line 1518

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add Shortcode
function get_sale_price( $atts ) {
if( function_exists('get_product') ){

    $sale_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
    $regular_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
    $percentage = round( ( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100 );
    return 'Meno' . $percentage.'%';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'get_sale_price', 'get_sale_price' );
```

Resolved with the use of this code, even if it's slow

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some shortcode for percentage offer, and finally i found some article, perhaps this can help anyone:

```
function get_sale_price( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'bartag' );

    $html = '';
    $salep = '';
    $prodp = '';

    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
         $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
        $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = $_product->get_price();
        $html =  round((($regular_price - $sale_price) / $regular_price) * 100). '%';
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'get_sale_price', 'get_sale_price' );
```

and you can use this too:

```
$_product->get_regular_price();
$_product->get_sale_price();
$_product->get_price();
```